# SharedPreferences across separate activities in the same application

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm having some trouble restored SharedPreferences into an activity separate from the original.

I have two classes that are utilizing this, "NewCustomerActivity" and "OldCustomerActivity". Both should have read/write access to the file - currently I'm just testing by writing from NewCustomerActivity, which will appropriately restore form data upon killing the activity; however I'm receiving a FC upon opening OldCustomerActivity which is attempting to restore the data in the same sense as NewCustomerActivity with a NullPointerException.

NewCustomerActivity:

```
public class NewCustomerActivity extends Activity {

public static final String USER_INFO = "UserInfoFile"; // This file will the store the user's information for later use.

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newcustomer);
    SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences(USER_INFO, 0); // Restore our earlier saved info.
    EditText et;
   ...... (Other code is irrelevant)
}
```

OldActivityNew is the same:

```
public class OldCustomerActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.oldcustomer);

    SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences(NewCustomerActivity.USER_INFO, 0); // Restore our earlier saved info.
    EditText et;

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
    et.setText(userInfo.getString("name",""));
..... (Continue to fill forms in this context)
}
```

Both of the activities fill the form with previous information, and update the file upon submission if anything has changed; however only NewCustomerActivity seems to be populating the file (Or not force closing to be specific)

I've tried setting up the SharedPreference in MODE_WORLD_READABLE (second parameter = 1) as well to no avail; even though I believe I should be able to run it in PRIVATE as it is. I've also tried referencing USER_INFO as NewCustomerActivity.USER_INFO

I must be missing something obvious - but any help would be appreciated as this is my first attempt, thanks!

Edit:

For those asking how I am writing to the file:

```
        SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences(USER_INFO, 0); // Save info for later
        SharedPreferences.Editor userInfoEditor = userInfo.edit();
        EditText et;
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
        String nameValue = et.getText().toString();
        userInfoEditor.putString("name", nameValue);
```

Comment: How are you trying to write to the SharedPreference in each activity?

Comment: Here's a snippet:

SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences(USER_INFO, 0); // Save info for later
  SharedPreferences.Editor userInfoEditor = userInfo.edit();
  EditText et;

  et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
  String nameValue = et.getText().toString();
  userInfoEditor.putString("name", nameValue);

Comment: Looks like you aren't committing your write operation. For `SharedPreferences` to take effect, after you are done with all your edits, you need to do a `userInfoEditor.commit();`

Comment: Thanks for the help - but as I said earlier; I'm writing everything properly (I'm calling commit as well at the end - I only posted a short snippet here as I had stated) I'm only having trouble with the read in the second activity (OldCustomerActivity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the preferences in `oldCustomerActivity` using a different mode than that which you wrote them.
Change this line in that class:

`getSharedPreferences(NewCustomerActivity.USER_INFO, 1)`

to use a 0 for the mode parameter:

`getSharedPreferences(NewCustomerActivity.USER_INFO, 0)`

The int you pass to the function doesn't define if you are reading or writing, but defines how you want the preferences to behave after you first write them.

To edit the preferences after you have loaded them you need to call:

`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userInfo .edit();`

You can then set the variables like this:

`editor.putString("username", "Ash");`

More information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: Sorry - that's a typo. I actually had them both originally as '0' (MODE_PRIVATE) and had changed them to to '1' (MODE_WORLD_READABLE) to see if that would change anything (Under the assumption that possibly private meant it must be in the same activity although the documentation states application.' I use the editor to write the preferences as you have stated as well (Just I didn't show it - it's in another function that I use for when the form is submitted) Everything seems to have been written correctly since I can reload the data in the NewCustomerActivity Activity, but thanks for the input

Comment: Oh well! If you're in Eclipse then open up Logcat and it will show the error that is thrown when the app force closes.